# Bootstrap modal form not displaying on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase, bootstrap-4

I have a website that I am making with bootstrap, firebase and JQuery. I have a button that when clicked is supposed to display a modal so the user can enter data. The data will be saved in my firebase database and then displayed on a table on the website. However, no matter what I do nothing happens when I click the button. The modal does not display.
This is what the modal looks like:

[image: Modal that is meant to appear]

```js
import { getDatabase } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-database.js";
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-app.js";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxx"
};
  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = firebase.database(app);
  coleccionProductos = db.ref().child('productos');
  bodyProductos = $('#bodyProductos').val();
  console.log(bodyProductos);  
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = $('#id').val();
    let codigo = $('#codigo').val();
    let descripcion = $('#descripcion').val();
    let cantidad = $('#cantidad').val();
    let idFirebase = id;
    if(idFirebase == ''){
     idFirebase = coleccionProductos.push().key;
    }
    data = {codigo:codigo, descripcion: descripcion, cantidad: cantidad};
    actualizacionData = {};
    actualizacionData[`/${idFirebase}`] = data;
    coleccionProductos.update(actualizacionData);
    id = '';
    $('form').trigger('reset');
    $('#modalAltaEdicion').modal('hide');
  });
  const iconoEditar = '';
  const iconoBorrar = '';
  function mostrarProductos({codigo, descripcion, cantidad}){
    return `
    <td>${codigo}</td>
    <td>${descripcion}</td>
    <td>${cantidad}</td>
    <td><button class="btnEditar btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar">${iconoEditar}</button><button class="btnBorrar btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Borrar">${iconoBorrar}</button></td>
    `
  }
  
  //Buttons programming
  $('#btnNuevo').click(function(){
    $('#id').val('');
    $('#codigo').val('');
    $('#descripcion').val('');
    $('#cantidad').val('');
    $('form').trigger('reset');
    $('#modalAltaEdicion').modal('show');
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Firebase CRUD</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <button id="btnNuevo" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Nuevo Producto"><svg class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.5H4a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h3.5V12a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V8.5H12a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H8.5V4z"/></svg></button>
              <!--Modal-->
                <div id="modalAltaEdicion" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-light">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">High / edition</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                                <form>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <input id="id" type="hidden"> <!-- ID we are going to receive from Firebase -->
                                    <div class="form-group">                                    
                                      <label>Code</label>
                                      <input id="codigo" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>Description</label>
                                      <input id="descripcion" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>Quantity</label>
                                      <input id="cantidad" type="number" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" tabindex="2">Cancelar</button>
                                    <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-primary" translate="1">Guardar</button>
                                </div>
                               </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              <table id="tablaProductos" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="bg-dark text-light">
                    <th scope="col">CODE</th>
                    <th scope="col">DESCRIPTION</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quantity </th>
                    <th scope="col">ACTIONS</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              <tbody id="bodyProductos">
              </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.14.4/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script type = "module" src = "firestore.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to add same ID to **data-target="#modalAltaEdicion"** and modal **id="modalAltaEdicion"** Now it's working! cheers

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Firebase CRUD</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <button id="btnNuevo" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAltaEdicion" title="Nuevo Producto"><svg class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.5H4a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h3.5V12a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V8.5H12a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H8.5V4z"/></svg></button>
              <!--Modal-->
                <div id="modalAltaEdicion" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-light">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">High / edition</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                                <form>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <input id="id" type="hidden"> <!-- ID we are going to receive from Firebase -->
                                    <div class="form-group">                                    
                                      <label>Code</label>
                                      <input id="codigo" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>Description</label>
                                      <input id="descripcion" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>Quantity</label>
                                      <input id="cantidad" type="number" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" tabindex="2">Cancelar</button>
                                    <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-primary" translate="1">Guardar</button>
                                </div>
                               </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              <table id="tablaProductos" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="bg-dark text-light">
                    <th scope="col">CODE</th>
                    <th scope="col">DESCRIPTION</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quantity </th>
                    <th scope="col">ACTIONS</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              <tbody id="bodyProductos">
              </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.14.4/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script type = "module" src = "firestore.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace **data-toggle="tooltip"** to **data-toggle="modal"** in the button.

<button id="btnNuevo" class="btn btn-primary" **data-toggle="tooltip"** title="Nuevo Producto">

Comment: Hello I tried adding `data-toggle="modal` to my button instead of tooltip but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

the data-target attribute should be added to target the model and also data-toggle should be assigned to "modal"

```
<button id="btnNuevo" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAltaEdicion" title="Nuevo Producto">
```

[Demo Documentation Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/)

Comment: Hello I tried this out but it still does not seem to work for me